# Traefik on Kubernetes does not keep path over redirect

Tags: kubernetes, traefik, traefik-ingress

I have a Traefik on Kubernetes that acts as ingress and load balancer. 
I have a ingress setup like this:

```
{
    "apiVersion": "extensions/v1beta1",
    "kind": "Ingress",
    "metadata": {
        "name": "nppl-ingress",
        "annotations": {
            "kubernetes.io/ingress.class": "traefik",
            "traefik.frontend.rule.type": "PathPrefixStrip"
        }
    },
    "spec": {
        "rules": [
            {
                "host": "" ,
                "http": {
                    "paths": [
                        {
                            "path": "/discover-service",
                            "backend": {
                                "serviceName": "discover-service",
                                "servicePort": "discover-port"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "path": "/config-server",
                            "backend": {
                                "serviceName": "config-server",
                                "servicePort": "config-port"
                            }
                        }

                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

When, for example, I hit "http://IP/config-server", because I have a basic auth on that service, the service does a redirect over "http://IP/login" so I get a 404 but I was expecting "http://IP/config-server/login". 
What is wrong with my configuration? I also tried "PathPrefix" and "Path" under rule type but it doesn't work. 
I need to keep my base path when my services perform redirects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that `PathPrefixStrip` removes `/config-server` and it initially forwards the request to your backend with just `/`. However, when your backend redirects it's a new request and the Ingress doesn't understand the request to `/` or `/login`. You could create two Ingress(es) for each backend and use single backend in each with a path to `/`. But this would mean adding a new ingress-class and [the good news is that `Traefik` supports it](https://github.com/containous/traefik/pull/3516). You could also try [an nginx](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/cli-arguments/) ingress which has the `--ingress-class` option.

You can find more information on how to create multiple ingress controllers [here](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/tree/master/examples/multiple-ingress-controllers)

If you want a single Ingress it will also be tricky since you might have to add logic in your app to understand the `/config-server` path for example.

Comment: Could you please provide an example? I have mapped under / the config-server so now I have two ingresses with / path and /config-server path but under / I had a traefik dashboard that now isn't showed anymore.

Comment: So added more details? Would you consider using an nginx ingress?  You can change the `ingress class` which would allow you to use multiple ingresses.

Comment: Also, opened a [ticket](https://github.com/containous/traefik/issues/3950) for Traefik.

Comment: could you provide some example of creating two ingresses for each backend?
Thanks for the ticket anyway!

Comment: @Justin added more details. Basically some info [here](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/tree/master/examples/multiple-ingress-controllers)